# Tweepy OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, tweepy, urllib3

Python 3.6. I use the streamer of tweepy to get tweets. It works well. But sometimes, if I let it open for more than 24h, I have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 277, in recv_into
return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1547, in recv_into
self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1353, in _raise_ssl_error
raise WantReadError()
  OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 277, in recv_into
return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1547, in recv_into
self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 1370, in _raise_ssl_error
raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
yield
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 384, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 483, in readinto
return self._readinto_chunked(b)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 578, in _readinto_chunked
chunk_left = self._get_chunk_left()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 546, in _get_chunk_left
chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 506, in _read_next_chunk_size
line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 293, in recv_into
return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 282, in recv_into
raise SocketError(str(e))
OSError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 File "twitter_aspi_v0.8.py", line 179, in _init_stream
tweepy.Stream(auth, listener).userstream()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 396, in userstream
self._start(async)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 363, in _start
self._run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 296, in _run
raise exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 265, in _run
self._read_loop(resp)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 315, in _read_loop
line = buf.read_line().strip()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 180, in read_line
self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 401, in read
raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 320, in _error_catcher
raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(10054, \'WSAECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')",))
```

My code is pretty long and regarding the error, it seems it comes from urllib3, OpenSSL and tweepy way of accessing the Twitter API. So I could handle this with a `try` before launching the streamer but I would like to know if there is maybe a better fix I could do to understand and avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Are you running this code at home or on a server?

Comment: @Prateek as i said my code doesn't handle the connection part, i just launch the streamer of tweepy with one fonction and then tweepy handle the connection

Comment: @TarunLalwani On a server, it works 90% of the time but sometimes it stops with this error

Comment: This looks more like a temporary connection timeout which is not handled by Tweepy, so you should just write a wrapper around the same and catch the exception and restart it. I don't think the exception can be avoided as such because you connect to an external site and sometimes it could timeout

Comment: @TarunLalwani ok i wanted to be sure, thanks !

Comment: You should look at this http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html#handling-errors for the error handling part and see if `on_error` gets called in your case when connection timeout happens

Comment: Check limits on the site [1](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/things-every-developer-should-know)  [2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html) [3](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html) there is no alternative than to restart stream connection via tweepy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks more like a temporary connection timeout which is not handled by `Tweepy`, so you should just write a wrapper around the same and catch the exception and restart it. I don't think the exception can be avoided as such because you connect to an external site and sometimes it could timeout

You should look at this http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html#handling-errors for the error handling part and see if `on_error` gets called in your case when connection timeout happens

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
```

If this doesn't help then use the wrapper approach

Answer (score 2):

According to Twitter Developer documentation : [rate limiting](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html) this is expected to connection reset/failure when you cross your usage limit.

> Requests / 15-min window (user auth)  = 900
>
> Requests / 15-min window (app auth)    = 1500

Also it clearly states as below.

If the initial reconnect attempt is unsuccessful, your client should continue attempting to reconnect using an exponential back-off pattern until it successfully reconnects.

(**Update**)

> Regardless of how your client gets disconnected, you should configure
> your app to reconnect immediately. If your first reconnection attempt
> is unsuccessful, we recommend that your app implement an exponential
> back-off pattern in subsequent reconnection attempts (e.g. wait 1
> second, then 2 seconds, then 4, 8, 16, etc), with some reasonable
> upper limit. If this upper limit is reached, you should configure your
> client to notify your team so that you can investigate further.

The standard (free) Twitter APIs i.e Tweepy API consist of a REST API and a Streaming API. The Streaming API provides low-latency access to Tweets. Ads API has other limits when white listed.

#### REST API Limit

> Clients may access a theoretical maximum of 3,200 statuses via the
> page and count parameters for the user_timeline REST API methods.
> Other timeline methods have a theoretical maximum of 800 statuses.
> Requests for more than the limit will result in a reply with a status
> code of 200 and an empty result in the format requested. Twitter still
> maintains a database of all the Tweets sent by a user. However, to
> ensure performance, this limit is in place on the API calls.

Could be simple reason that users should not spam that this thing is enforced.

#### Solution :

You may catch `exception` and re-establish connection to Twitter and continue reading tweets.

There is no alternative than getting better usage allowance from Twitter as of now unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as i use the streaming API the limit are not the same than the Rest API. And I already had rate limiting error with the streaming API and the error is not the same as the one i've posted