# Python: Exception not getting caught in Tweepy for WantReadError

Tags: python, openssl, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to capture the Twitter streaming API. As with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530034/tweepy-openssl-ssl-wantreaderror), I will occasionally get a series of errors when there's a problem with the connection, beginning with

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 256, in recv_into
return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1335, in recv_into
self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1149, in _raise_ssl_error
raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError
```

followed by several other "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:" errors.

As implied in that previous question, these errors are not caught by Tweepy's `on_error` and similar methods. However, I'm not clear on how to write a wrapper to try to catch this. I originally started my stream with

```
twitterStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=myListener)
```

where `myListener` is my regular class. I tried wrapping this with

```
try:
    twitterStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=myListener)
except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError as e:
    logger.error('WantReadError: %s', e)
```

but I get an "undefined name" error here in my IDE, because the OpenSSL thing isn't something I have directly in my code and I'm not sure how to call it. But even if I change this to `except Exception as e:`, it still doesn't catch this error. (I know that ultimately I want to restart the stream, probably with an increasing backoff delay, but for now I'm just trying to see if I can simply catch the error.)

What's the right way to catch this, and keep my stream going? Obviously this is a bot that's supposed to run forever, so I'd like not to have to keep looking at it to make sure it's still going if there's a network hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is defined in the OpenSSL library, so you can't call it normally.  All you should have to use to fix this is

```
import OpenSSL
```

and the error should start being recognised in your program.

You should already have this library pip installed (one of the libraries you're using is already depending on it!) But just in case it's not for some reason, you can use:

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

Hope that helps.